# NewLine problem when converting from UTF-8 to IBM-273 using iconv

Tags: mainframe, iconv, jcl

I'm using JCL to copy a file/dataset from USS to MVS, which should in the next step be converted from UTF-8 to IBM-273. This generally works but the linebreaks which are set using "**\n**" are converted to a "**.**".

Converting is done like that:

```
CONV  EXEC PGM=EDCICONV,PARM=('FROMCODE(UTF-8),TOCODE(IBM-273)')
```

Hoping for some input!

Comment: What is the hex value of the '.'? You do realise that a '.' is not necessarily a 'period' but can represent an 'unprintable/undisplayable' character? This is probably not a JCL problem unless you have failed to provide the desired dataset names. It is more likely a misunderstanding of what EDCICONV can do or incorrect control cards (which are not JCL).

Comment: Also note that z/OS datasets don't work with things like "linebreaks". While it may have the correct binary value it does not work as such when e.g. viewing the file with ISPF edit/browse.

Comment: You might find the "." is the EBCIDIC new-line character. It could be a file attribute issue. Without more details it is difficult to tell

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, EDCICONV program will not split your file into separate records using \n or \r\n and you will end up with one long record.

You can do it slightly different and first of all convert your UTF-8 file to IBM in USS
using following command:

```
iconv -f UTF-8 -t IBM-273 /path/to/inputFile.txt > /path/to/outputFile.txt
```

then move this converted file to mvs using following command:

```
cp -W "seqparms='RECFM=VB,LRECL=1000'" /path/to/outputFile.txt "//'DATA.SET.NAME'"
```

use your DCB parameters, LRECL and RECFM specified as an example..
You can also  use your OCOPY JCL program to copy it.. i guess it should be the same..

another option is to create a Java program, that will convert your dataset from utf-8 to ibm-273..